# What do we earn by making global variables as non-global variables by using static keyword?

Tags: c

I have learned that those global variables that will not be used outside the file should be made non-global variable by appending static keyword like `static int a;`

I want to know that why we should do this?

Comment: You can't *accidentally* use it in another file.

Comment: @user253751 So for only this purpose, we make non-global variables?

Answer (score 0):

Static implies a translation unit level scope only.

However, you don't need to make it non-global + static.

You can very well make it global static to curb the scope to translation unit level.

Comment: Translation unit* scope. Not file scope.